# Flowtype not detecting type of property inside object

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am hitting the following error

```
 90:             var b = action.data;
                                ^^^^ property `data`. Property not found in
 90:             var b = action.data;
                         ^^^^^^ object type
```

This is inside a function that receives `action` as an argument like this:

```
export default (state: SecurityGroupState = { groups: null, editingIPRange: null }, action: Action) => {
```

The type `Action` is imported using `import type` like so:

```
import type { Action } from "../../actions";
```

And it is declared as so:

```
export type Action = {
    type: string,
    data: Object,
} | {
    type: string,
    error: Object,
};
```

The code that is triggering the initial error is the following:

```
switch (action.type) {
case GET:
    if (action.error) {
        console.error(action.error);
        break;
    }

    var a = action.data; // no error here
    const groupsCopy2 = _.map(state.groups, () => {
        var b = action.data;
    });
}
```

So in the `var a = ...` line, Flow is OK with `action.data`, but inside the `map` lambda it doesn't seem to know that `action: Action` can have a `data` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow is pessimistic about refinements, it considers that every function call could modify `action.data`. As for a fix, you can use a `const` [binding](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#caveats)

```
const data = action.data
const groupsCopy2 = _.map(state.groups, () => {
  var b = data;
});
```